# c# how to use myclass.object1.child as a whole one argument?

Tags: c#

Here is my class:

```
class InfoClass
{
    public string source;
    public InfoItem tests { get; set; }
    public InfoItem serverBuild { get; set; }
    public InfoItem localBuild { get; set; }
    public InfoItem installedBuild { get; set; }

    public void pull()
    {
        InfoClass newInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InfoClass>(File.ReadAllText(this.source));
        this.tests = newInfo.tests;
        this.serverBuild = newInfo.serverBuild;
        this.localBuild = newInfo.localBuild;
        this.installedBuild = newInfo.installedBuild;
    }
    public void push()
    {
        File.WriteAllText(this.source, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this));
    }
}

public class InfoItem
{
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string updated { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I create instance of this class in another file, e.g:

```
InfoClass info = new InfoClass()
```

And then I use pull and push to update some values:

```
        info.pull();
        info.serverBuild.status = "checking";
        info.push();
```

What I want is to create some auxiliary method to use it more often and esier. Something like this:

```
info.Update(serverBuild.status, "checking"); //instead of above 3 lines
```

Comment: Why not to include that method inside your InfoClass??

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: This would just be a new function on the `InfoClass` class named `Update` that calls the three lines you have above. Basically just a wrapper function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write an extension:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void Update<T>(this T info, Action<T> action) where T : InfoClass
    {
        info.pull();
        action(info);
        info.push();
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
info.Update(x=>{x.serverBuild.status = "test";});
```

Comment: Small remark for your solution : `Action<T>` requires a parameter of type `T` and in your code you've done `action();` instead of `action(info);`

Comment: Where should I put  public static Extensions ??

Comment: In file name MyExtensions.cs

Comment: It does not work for me, compiler gives an error:

`Extensions must be defined in non generic static class`

Comment: It is because I forgot to write 'class' after static. I fixed my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it's the closest to my assumptions and a quite simple solution

Answer (score 0):

You can create method inside your `InfoClass` let's say :

```
public void Update(string name, object value)
{
    pull(); // pull from here
    // split name into "path like"
    string[] path = name.Split('.', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    // set current path reference
    object current = this;
    for(int i = 0; i < path.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        string way = path[i];
        // reassign reference till the pre-last element
        current = current.GetType().GetProperty(way, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(current);
    }
    // set the new value 
    current.GetType().GetProperty(path[path.Length - 1], BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).SetValue(current, value);
    push(); // push from here
}
```

And then you can use it almost like you wanted but instead `info.Update(serverBuild.status, "checking");` you'll have `info.Update("serverBuild.status", "checking");`

[Check this online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4N9DkS)